# Sphinx: protecting words from stemming

Tags: dictionary, sphinx, protected

Is it possible in Sphinx to have a list of words that would be protected from stemming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wordforms
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-wordforms

*"it can also be used to implement stemming exceptions, because stemming is not applied to words found in the forms list."*

Just replace the word with itself, and it wont be stemmed

```
walking > walking
```